# Adicionar botões Próximo e Anterior incorporados no Player de Video HTML5

Tags: javascript, css3, html5-video

Estou buscando uma forma de fazer algo que o Youtube tem no app deles, porém, em uma player de video HTML5 Utilizando apenas HTML, CSS e Javascript/Typescript.

Vejam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu já possuo todo código e lógica do funcionamento dos botões. Porém não consigo encontrar referência em lugar nenhum para deixá-los estilizados desta forma. Eu sei que posso adicionar botões normais para Próximo e Anterior. Entretanto, estou tentando fazer algo incorporado ao vídeo, a exemplo de como já funciona os botões nativo Play e pause.

Comment: Detectando o fim do vídeo e colocando os botões sobre o player (position absolute) não funcionaria?

Comment: @caiocafardo acho q até pode funcionar. Acho q estava fixado em usar um recurso da tag de vídeo para isso e não pensei nisso. Vou testar aqui! ;)